# PDF displays empty the first time it's loaded on Android

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display a PDF on Android in a Xamarin.Forms project and it works fine, except for the first time it's loaded where just one blank page appears 9 times out of 10.

The first call is to this function, located in the Android project:

```
    public string HTMLToPDF(string html, string filename) {
        //html param is a full html description of the pdf
        //filename param is something like "example.pdf"

        try {
            var dir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/folder/");
            var file = new Java.IO.File(dir + "/" + filename);

            if (!dir.Exists())
                dir.Mkdirs();

            int x = 0;
            while (file.Exists())
            {
                x++;
                file = new Java.IO.File(dir + "/" + filename + "( " + x + " )");
            }

            if (webpage == null)
                webpage = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Android.App.Application.Context);
            else
                webpage.RemoveAllViews();

            int width = 2100;
            int height = 2970;

            webpage.Layout(0, 0, width, height);
            webpage.LoadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            webpage.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewCallBack(file.ToString()));

            this.Print(webpage, file.ToString(), filename);

            return file.ToString();
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {
            App._mainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", e.Message, "Ok");
        }

        return "";
    }
```

This is what the `WebViewCallBack` class looks like:

```
    class WebViewCallBack : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
    {
        string fileNameWithPath = null;

        public WebViewCallBack(string path)
        {
            this.fileNameWithPath = path;
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.SetInitialScale(1);
            view.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            view.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

            PdfDocument document = new Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument();
            Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(new Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(2100, 2970, 1).Create());                

            view.Draw(page.Canvas);

            document.FinishPage(page);

            Stream filestream = new MemoryStream();
            Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(fileNameWithPath, false);
            try
            {
                document.WriteTo(filestream);
                fos.Write(((MemoryStream)filestream).ToArray(), 0, (int)filestream.Length);
                fos.Close();
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {
                App._mainPage.DisplayAlert("Erreur", e.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the method `Print` called at the end:

```
    public void Print(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, string filename, string onlyFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
            PrintAttributes.Margins margins = new PrintAttributes.Margins(0, 0, 0, 80);

            builder.SetMinMargins(margins);
            builder.SetMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.IsoA4);
            builder.SetColorMode(PrintColorMode.Color);

            PrintAttributes attr = builder.Build();

            PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.PrintService);

            var printAdapter = new GenericPrintAdapter(Forms.Context, webView, filename, onlyFileName);
            printAdapter.OnEnded += PrintAdapter_OnEnded;
            printAdapter.OnError += PrintAdapter_OnError;

            printManager.Print(filename, printAdapter, attr);
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {
            App._mainPage.DisplayAlert("Erreur", e.Message, "Ok");
        }
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on the first line of the `OnPageFinished` callback of the `WebViewCallBack` class, I see two different things at this point:

- either the PDF interface is up but it's still loading the PDF. In that case, the PDF loads fine once I click on "play" again.
- either the PDF has already loaded, as a single blank page. This only happens when it's the first try at loading this particular PDF.

Thus I guess I have to find a way to force the loader to wait for the `OnPageFinished` method to run first? But that seems wrong.

I can also add that the original HTML contains images, which are all appearing as base64 string in the html string I'm feeding to `HTMLToPDF`. I noticed that the PDF loads well even on the first try if there are no images in the HTML, so I thought the problem might be that the PDF loads before it's ready on the first try only, maybe because of the images. I couldn't find a fix for that though.

Can anybody shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Have you tried loading the HTML _after_ setting the WebViewClient?

Comment: Unfortunately, putting `LoadData` right after `SetWebViewClient` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways to handle the flow, but I would go with just an event or an Observable.

So lets convert your `WebViewCallBack` to something that actually performs a callback when its `OnPageFinished` is called. This is using `System.Reactive` but you could also use an `EventHandler`...

```
// a few class level variables
bool busy;
WebView webView;
IDisposable WhenPageIsLoadedSubscription;

public class WebViewObservable : WebViewClient
{
    Subject<string> pageLoaded = new Subject<string>();

    public IObservable<string> WhenPageIsLoaded
    {
        get { return pageLoaded.AsObservable(); }
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        pageLoaded.OnNext(url);
    }
}
```

Now define your print routine (the calls in your original OnPageFinished and Print method). This will automatically be called when the webpage is finished loading.

```
void PrintWebPage(WebView webView, string url)
{
    Log.Debug("SO", $"Page: {url} loaded, lets print it now" );

    // Perform the work that you used to do in OnPageFinished

    // Perform the work in your Print method

    // Now turn off a Progress indictor if desired

    busy = false;
}
```

Setup your `WebView` with the observable that calls the `PrintWebPage` action every time a page is loaded...

```
void LoadAndPrintWebPage(string html))
{
    busy = true;
    if (webView == null)
    {
        int width = 2100;
        int height = 2970;

        webView = new WebView(this);
        var client = new WebViewObservable();
        WhenPageIsLoadedSubscription = client.WhenPageIsLoaded.Subscribe((url) => { PrintWebPage(webView, url); });
        webView.SetWebViewClient(client);
        webView.Layout(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    webView.LoadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

Now call `LoadWebPage` with your html content and it will be automatically printed after the page is finished loading...

```
 LoadAndPrintWebPage(html);
```

When you are done, clean up your observable and webview to avoid memory leaks...

```
void CleanupWebView()
{
    WhenPageIsLoadedSubscription?.Dispose();
    webView?.Dispose();
    webView = null;
}
```

Comment: I had to use an `EventHandler` because my project isn't compatible with `System.Reactive` but I managed to make it work. Thank you very much!

Although it loads infinitely when there are multiple photos in the HTML page I'm feeding, do you know how to resolve that?

Comment: @yurden And all those images are embedded base64 strings? How large are those "html strings"?

Comment: Yes they are. The user can take some pictures during his use of the app and all those pictures have to appear on the PDF. It has to work even with 100 photos, and it's important they are not compressed to ugly-level. Right now, it loads infinitely if there are 3 or more photos. I can't count characters of one of those base64 string right now, but they are thousands of char. long. Once opened in a fullscreen modal on tablet, the modal displays a very tiny scrollbar, just to give you an idea.

Comment: @yurden How many images are on each PDF page? And what is the image resolution of each? I would assume it is a memory issue AND a CPU decoding speed issue. If the html string is saved to a file, what happens if you launch Chrome (via an intent) with that local file url? After testing that and failing(?), I would approach it by saving the images to individual files and load just the html that includes `img` elements to each image and see what happens when you load that in Chrome via intent and then go back to your WebView print routine.

Comment: Otherwise construct html pages one by one, print to file each page to a separate file and then stitch them all into one pdf in the end.

Comment: Damn I went and checked the resolution of the pictures taken inside the app and it was way higher than it should have been. I fixed it and now it's working fine, I didn't test beyond ~50 pictures for now but it should be fine. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with blank page. But I used google doc for displaying it. `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=`

I could solved my problem only by checking operation time between `OnPageStarted`  and `OnPageFinished`. If it took short time, then something go wrong and page is blank.

here is my webClient.

Every time then page is blank I just reload it. Also add simple circuit breaker just in case

```
    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private readonly WebView _webView;
        private DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        private int _breakerHits;
        private const int _BreakerCount = 2;

        public MyWebViewClient(WebView webView)
        {
            _webView = webView;
        }

        public override async void OnPageStarted(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
            _dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            _webView.SendNavigating(new WebNavigatingEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, null, url));
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }

        public override async void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            if (url.Contains(".pdf"))
            {
                var diff = DateTime.Now - _dateTime;
                if (diff > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(700) || _breakerHits > _BreakerCount)
                {
                    _breakerHits = 0;
                    _webView.SendNavigated(new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, null, url,
                        WebNavigationResult.Success));
                }
                else
                {
                    _breakerHits++;
                    view.Reload();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                _webView.SendNavigated(new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, null, url,
                    WebNavigationResult.Success));
            }

            _semaphoreSlim.Release();

        }
    }
```